# Understand interphone 4+N wiring and arrow symbol

Tags: schematics, wiring, symbol

Could anybody help me understand the attached interphone 4+N wiring? specially the arrow symbol crossing a  two segments right angle, what it means, what is it connecting?
I have an issue with an interphone not working, no ring, no speaker, no mic.
Is there any color code used on the 5 wires? One wire was disconnected, I reproduced the wiring based on my neighbour's but still isn't working.
Any help debugging the issue will be more than welcome.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea, but given that the illustration suggests a telephone-style user interface, I'm wondering whether those are hook switch functions. But what they do electrically is a complete mystery. The two at the top appear to connect the microphone/speaker to the audio buses, but the function of the third one is not obvious. Can you open one up and take pictures of it?

Comment: Is there a push-to-talk button on the handset?

Comment: I just added a picture. Yes, there is a button that may have 2 or 3 positions: hook-off to listen/talk, hang and push to open the door.